# Sales promotion not removed when required items removed

Tags: magento-1.6, promotions, shopping-cart-price-rules

We have an issue with our site where if you add items in a promotion (eg. buy x and y and get z% off y), then remove one of the items (x) you still get the discount (on y). I'm a bit of a self taught noob when it comes to magento and PHP so I don't even know where I would look, does anyone have any ideas?

[image: Conditions]

[image: Actions]

Comment: Perhaps you can add a screenshot of your conditions and actions?

Comment: Hey benmarks, thanks for the reply, I have added the conditions and actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the colleague who set this particular promotion accidentally put the affected items in both sets of conditions - should have checked this first!